# Where do you get/find the JWT-Secret from firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I'm using firebase for my web/mobile apps and now have a back-end API I'm looking to use as well.
The API requires a JWT token to authenticate the requests and to set it up, I need to specify the JWT Secret that is used to encrypt/decrypt the token.

In firebase, I believe I retrieve the token using
const token  = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(); This is what I pass to the API.

However, I have not figured out where I get the JWT-secret to configure? I have tried the API key that is shown in firebase console, I have also tried the server/client keys found at my console at https://console.developers.google.com.

however, no matter what, I'm getting a JWSInvalidSignature when trying to make requests to the API Call.

Has anyone got this working? Where do I get the JWT-secret from firebase to configure on the API back-end? Thanks in advance.

Here are the details:
1. I am using a service called postGrest which auto-creates a web API on top of postgres DB. In order to authenticate the requests, you configure the service by  specifying a custom claim called "role", and you also need to specify the JWT-secret so it can decode the token.

Here is my simple call to the API:

```
           const fetchdata = async () => {
           const token  = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();

        let axiosConfig = {
           headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token
                   } 
             }
       const data = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/users`, 
       axiosConfig);
}
```

Also note, I can simulate this in the bash command line using the following code: Note here that I'm getting the token from the getIdToken() above.

```
   export TOKEN="eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImQ2YzM5Mzc4YWVmYzA2YzQyYTJlODI1OTA0ZWNlZDMwODg2YTk5MjIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiI1NSIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc2VjdXJldG9rZW4uZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9wb3N0Z3Jlc3QtYjRjOGMiLCJhdWQiOiJwb3N0Z3Jlc3QtYjRjOGMiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1NzExNTIyMjQsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJNMXZwQ3A2ZjlsaFdCblRleHh1TjlEdXIzUXAyIiwic3ViIjoiTTF2cENwNmY5bGhXQm5UZXh4dU45RHVyM1FwMiIsImlhdCI6MTU3MTE1OTQ0NSwiZXhwIjoxNTcxMTYzMDQ1LCJlbWFpbCI6InNwb25nZWJvYkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6ZmFsc2UsImZpcmViYXNlIjp7ImlkZW50aXRpZXMiOnsiZW1haWwiOlsic3BvbmdlYm9iQGdtYWlsLmNvbSJdfSwic2lnbl9pbl9wcm92aWRlciI6InBhc3N3b3JkIn19.nKuovs0Gx_ZKp17dI3kfz6GQofIMEOTA8RqTluwEs-5r-oTbKgpG33uS7fs7txVxvWIb_3fbN3idzfDHZevprMkagbHOd73CxTFBM7pr1bD2OKSK9ZPYfSt9OhvgJL51vBN3voLcNAb5iWVVl2XMqkcXeDoBi8IOKeZr27_DsRx48GSi7HieHWscF1lujSEr2C9tdAek3YyNnr3IcGI8cTSPHPaIbYl-8CaHQO2fUiGHEAaD7sqHxp3otJio56zOoNAy44P_nwORlMFZC0Rm8SaATpbmIkgbGYWHZHty70lmlYGVHTuM_hr2s7z2YhAjuacvBMgusZpyoVnoe3FQeA"

    curl http://localhost:8080/contacts -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
```

What's returned is: {"message":"JWSError JWSInvalidSignature"}

For the JWT-secret, I have tried several values, but none seem to work. This includes the "API Key" from firebase project, as well as trying "Generate key" which downloads a new .json file and inside there is a "private_key": that is along string.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the code that isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: updated post with snippet of code. The gist is I need to provide this api tool the JWT secret so it can decode the firebase token...and I don't know where i get that (or if I can)

Comment: And what code are you writing on the backend to validate the token which isn't working the way you expect?

Comment: I don't write the code, it's a webserver app called Postgrest. Here is a link to simple tutorial they show how to configure the JWT secret: http://postgrest.org/en/v6.0/tutorials/tut1.html

Comment: I think it would help a lot here to know exactly what the backend is doing or expecting.

Comment: Well, I've used this simple tool to create a JWT token, and it works correctly with their site : https://jwt.io/#debugger-io . You just put in the JWT-secret, put in your claims and it shows the correct token. I then configure that jwt-secret in their app and works great. Do you know if/where to find this JWT secret on firebase?

Comment: Can you please update what is the solution?

Comment: For my solution , for the Key, I can just point to this url: https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com . That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

From [your service account](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk) downloaded file, use the `private_key` value to validate/decode the JWT token you got from `getIdToken()`...

The [steps for using a third-party library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) to validate a Firebase Auth ID token describe it in more detail.

Comment: it shows two certificates? Which one to use for JWT secret? Is the top one the public key/bottom one private?

Comment: Try them both and pick the one that works?  If the instructions in the documentation are insufficient, please reach out to Firebase support to explain what's not working the way you expect.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Tried both, still no luck. Thanks for the effort, I sent a ticket to firebase to see if they can assist.

Comment: Did you get the solution to this pls?

Comment: @mikehennessy what is the ticket # and did you get any resolution?

Comment: Any chance someone has the solution here? I've been searching everywhere and haven't stumbled on where the secret is defined yet.